# Backup and bz2 large mysql datefile with innobackupex in the background

Tags: database-administration, mysql, database-backup

I'm using the following command to backup a large running mysql database (~500GB).

```
innobackupex --user=user --password=***** --stream=tar ./db-backup | bzip2 - > backup.tar.bz2
```

Since the backup process takes more than 24 hours, I want to run the task in the background. Background task doesn't work unfortunately with the following command and as soon as my ssh session to the server is closed (or a connection reset occurs) backup process terminates:

```
nohup innobackupex --user=user --password=***** --stream=tar ./db-backup | bzip2 - > backup.tar.bz2
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `screen` or `tmux`. Alternatively, start it from a cron job.

Comment: Thanks, solved by installing screen, running it, running innobackupex without nohup, and then pressing Ctrl+a d to detach session.